# exponential of matrix in linear differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I am a bit confused about the following from my lecture note:

Suppose we have

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=-\epsilon y \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=by+cx
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation}

How do we get $$x(t)=A\exp\big(\frac{\epsilon c}{b}t\big)+B\exp\big(-|b|t\big)$$

---

I know the following

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\ \dot{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\epsilon\\ c & b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation}Since the matrix is upper-triangular matrix, so I have the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \exp(\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\epsilon\\ c & b\end{bmatrix})\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\ y_0\end{bmatrix} $$

Then how do I go to the next step? Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Use that $\exp(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}$

Comment: The other material is consistent, but $x(t)=A\exp\big(\frac{\epsilon c}{b}t\big)+B\exp\big(-|b|t\big)$ does not fit with it. The eigenvalues of the matrix have square roots in them, for example...

Comment: Your matrix is *not* upper-triangular.